# aligning different sized images to bottom

Tags: css, alignment

I have a series of floated images, each with different size, How can I do that the images to be aligned to bottom, not to top, I tried vertical-align, but it`s not wotking.

the code is something like this:

```
<div id="ngg-image-194" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box"
    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
        <img .... > </img>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="ngg-image-195" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box"
    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
        <img .... > </img>
   </div>
</div>
and so on .............
```

and the css is like this:

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
    float: left;
}
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail img {
height: auto;
}
#ngg-image-194 img {
width: 100px ;
}
#ngg-image-195 img {
width: 140px ;
}
and so on .............
```

Comment: I think working fiddle* or bin** can provide you better response and plus a tip, that `<img>` tag is self-closed.

* http://jsfiddle.net/
** http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to change?

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
    float: left;
}
```

to:

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Images will align to bottom if so

Comment: What??? Since when `display: inline block` causes elements to stick to the bottom?

Comment: Haha, isn't CSS full of surprises. It's not the bottom though, it's the baseline; but you can change that with `vertical-align`...

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a css trick to keep elements in bottom :

```
.class{
  position : absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a container with a position:relative;

```
<div id="container">

<div id="ngg-image-194" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box box">
    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
        <img .... > </img>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="ngg-image-195" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box box">
    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
        <img .... > </img>
   </div>
</div>

</div>
#container {
   position:relative;
   width:900px;
   height:900px;
}
.box {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
float:left;
margin-right:15px;

}
```